# Symfony2 simple many-to-many issue

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

I have a simple question,
I have two tables in relation many to many, Post and Category,
in an intact form PostType a collection of form CategoryType, but here the problems begin ..

I followed the instructions on the cookbook collection form to persist the data, I just do not get the desired result ..
Here's the code:

```
class Post
{
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categories", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="AnCat",
 *  joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *  },
 *  inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categories_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *  }
 * )
 **/
protected $categories;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->categories = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

public function addCategory($categories)
{
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $category->addPosts($this);
    }
    $this->categories[] = $categories;
}

class Categories
{
/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="categories")
 */
protected $posts;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->posts = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 *
 * @param Post $post
 * @return Categories
 */
public function addPosts(Post $posts)
{
   // I tried it but I get the same result!
   /*if (!$this->posts->contains($posts)) {
        $this->posts->add($posts);
    }*/

    $posts->addCategory($this);
    $this->posts[] = $posts;
}

class PostType extends AbstractType
{

->add('Categories', 'collection', array('type' => new CategoriesType(), 
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'prototype_name' => '__categ__',
                'by_reference' => false
            ))

class CategoriesType extends AbstractType
{
     ->add('category', 'entity', array(
            'attr' => array('class' => 'cat'),
            'class' => 'MyBusinessBundle:Categories',
            'property' => 'category',
            'label' => 'Categories'
        ))
```

The problem is that inserts a new field Category, instead of creating a simple relationship Post-Category.
I don't understand where I'm wrong ..

Comment: It inserts What and into What?

Comment: In what sense?
Can you be more specific?
I don't seem have missed information ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your postType, change collection type into entity Type

```
    class PostType extends AbstractType
    {
    $builder->add('Categories', 'entity',
        array( 'label' => 'Categories',
            'required' => false,
            'expanded' => true,
            'class' => 'xxx\xxxBundle\Entity\Categories',
            'property' => 'title',
            'multiple' => true,
        ));
```

In your post creation form you will have checkboxes with categories. If you want a multi select field, change expanded by false

Comment: Thank you, but the main problem is that I need a collection because, in this example have not made, Categories is linked one to many with subcategories and in CategoriesType there is the field categories that the field entity subcategories.

Comment: Perhap's your data modele is not very "clean"... You need to create a "join table" entity call (postCategory) with oneToMay relation with categorie, an other oneToMay relation with posts, subcat, type, ... After that, you can create a collection with all fields.